# Get value in range proportional to number in python 3.4

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, range

I'm plotting a set of 3 circles, all with the same y-coordinate.

I want the x-coordinate for them to be evenly spread on my axis, between -2 and 4, in proportion to the length of the row (which is 3 in this case as there are 3 circles).

I have to do this for multiple sets of circles, so the range is still the same however the length of the row changes.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might also try `numpy.arange`, but this will take a `step` parameter instead of number of count, and the `to` number is exclusive...

Comment: `numpy.linspace` takes a number count rather than a step, and the `to` number is inclusive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`numpy.linspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) for this

> **numpy.linspace(start,stop,num)**
>
> Return evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval.
>
> Returns num evenly spaced samples, calculated over the interval [start, stop ].

```
In [14]: start = -2
In [15]: stop = 4
In [16]: num = 3

In [17]: np.linspace(start,stop,num)
Out[17]: array([-2.,  1.,  4.])
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I actually thought of, just couldn't remember the right name, and when I found `arange` thought that would be it. (Now I see: `linspace` is even mentioned in `arange`'s docstring...)

Answer (score 1):

```
high = 4 # high boundary
low = -2 # low boundary
count = 3 # number of elements

# distance between two adjacent elements; there are (count - 1) spaces
# to fill, so calculate the size of each of those spaces
distance = (high - low) / (count - 1)
for i in range(count):
    x = low + distance * i
    print(x)
```

Yields:

```
-2.0
1.0
4.0
```

Comment: But shouldn't it yield `-2, 1, 4`? I think `distance` should be `(high - low) / (count - 1)` (provided that `count > 1`)

Comment: @tobias_k thank you both for your help! As I have to do this a few times for different row lengths/counts, is there a more pythonic way of doing this? (Maybe I should have noted this in the question - will edit now)

Comment: Just put it into a function that you can call then.